# How do you login via the WebEx URL REST API?

Tags: webex

I'm new to the Webex API and am trying to run my first few calls.  Starting with a login call, it looks to me like our REST url for that should be https://[ourSite].webex.com/[ourSite]/p.php?AT=LI

What I’m unclear about is how to authenticate.  The documentation ([page 2-22](https://developer.cisco.com/fileMedia/download/4588769e-3624-4778-9aa6-9456e8336a2f)) doesn’t list username or password as fields that can be sent.  The only field it lists as required is WID (Webex ID), which I assume is to be the authentication string?  If so, how does one find this value?  I do not see it in the user edit screen in site administration, which seems like the logical place for it to me.  Is there some special screen I need to access for API information like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be https://sitename.webex.com/sitename/p.php?AT=LI&WID=[WebExID]

It used to allow passing account password, meeting passwords and partner IDs in the URL itself, but a security update removed that functionality, so they must be passed in an HTTP POST form. Example:

```html
<form action="https://sitename.webex.com/sitename/p.php?AT=LI&WID=username" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="PW" value="">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Check out the blog post below for more details:

https://communities.cisco.com/community/developer/webex/blog/2016/02/11/recent-url-api-changes--get2post